Object created by L.GPX doesn't play nice with LayerGroups in Leaflet
I'm trying to make a layer control where I have two base layers and a bunch of imported GPX files. Here I first create my base layers, and just add them to a group.


var Stadia_Outdoors = L.tileLayer(
  "https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/outdoors/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.{ext}",
  {
    minZoom: 1,
    //maxZoom: 20,
    attribution:
      '&copy; <a href="https://www.stadiamaps.com/" target="_blank">Stadia Maps</a> &copy; <a href="https://openmaptiles.org/" target="_blank">OpenMapTiles</a> &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    ext: "png",
  }
);

var OpenTopoMap = L.tileLayer(
  "https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
  {
    minZoom: 1,
    //maxZoom: 20,
    attribution:
      'Map data: &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://viewfinderpanoramas.org">SRTM</a> | Map style: &copy; <a href="https://opentopomap.org">OpenTopoMap</a> (<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>)',
  }
);

var baseMaps = {
  Outdoor: Stadia_Outdoors,
  Topo: OpenTopoMap,
};



I iterate over some uploaded .gpx files and used this to get the data into my map.


function addGPX(url, iconSource) {
  new L.GPX(url, {
    async: true,
    markers: {
      wptIcons: {
        "": iconSource,
        iconSize: [30, 30],
        popupAnchor: [20, 20],
        
      },
    },
  }).on("loaded", function (e) {
    var name = e.target.get_name();
    var offsetThisShit = {
      offset: L.point(0, -20),
    };

    e.target.bindPopup(name, offsetThisShit); // fixes a placement issue with the pop-up
    map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
  });
}



But from L.GPX I get an object which I cannot add into a LayerGroup. I cant seem to find the solution. In my head I feel it should work when I add all the objects into an array and pass the array to the group. or uses the addTo() to add objects to the group.
(I'm new to leaflet, so I'm sorry if this is a very basic question)

So I finally solved it by my self. Maybe someone have the same confusion later.
My problem was that I didn't place the layerGroup in an object before I tried to pass it through the L.control.layers().
So the code should be:


var GPX_file_1 = new L.GPX("gpx_1_filename.gpx", {
  async: true,
}).on("loaded", function (e) {
  var name = e.target.get_name();
  var offsetThisShit = {
    offset: L.point(0, -20),
  };

  e.target.bindPopup(name, offsetThisShit);
  map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
});

var GPX_file_2 = new L.GPX("gpx_2_filename.gpx", {
  async: true,
}).on("loaded", function (e) {
  var name = e.target.get_name();
  var offsetThisShit = {
    offset: L.point(0, -20),
  };

  e.target.bindPopup(name, offsetThisShit);
  map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
});

var gpxGroup = L.layerGroup([GPX_file_1, GPX_file_2]);

// Layer control
var baseMaps = {
  Outdoor: Stadia_Outdoors,
  Topo: OpenTopoMap,
};

var overlayMaps = {
  "GPX Tracks": gpxGroup,
};

L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);


console.log(nyGPX2);
var someOtherShit = {
  displayName: [nyGPX, nyGPX2],
};



